# How to make video driver work in Debian Jessie

Tags: drivers, backlight

I have an Acer Aspire ES1-531-P8JN. It has the Intel N3700 CPU with integrated graphics. I have the problem that the video driver i915 does not seem to work in Debian Jessie 8.3.0, even though it does work on (L)Ubuntu 15.10. I am concerned about this, because I'd like the program `xbacklight` to work on Debian, too, because I actually prefer Debian over Ubuntu, but had to switch to Lubuntu, because my eyes got really strained.

Here is what I get for `sudo lshw -c video` in Debian:

```
  *-display UNCLAIMED
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 21
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:90000000-90ffffff memory:80000000-8fffffff ioport:2000(size=64)
```

And here is what I get in Lubuntu:

```
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 21
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:312 memory:90000000-90ffffff memory:80000000-8fffffff ioport:2000(size=64)
```

`lsmod | grep i915` in Debian gives me:

```
i915                           837175  0 
drm_kms_helper         49210        1   i915
drm                             249955  2   i915,drm_kms_helper
i2c_algo_bit                12751       1   i915
video                            18096      2   i915,acer_wmi
button                      12944       1   i915
i2c_core                    46012       7   drm,i915,i2c_hid,drm_kms_helper,i2c_algo_bit,v4l2_common,videodev
```

And in Lubuntu:

```
i915                       1130496     4
i2c_algo_bit                16384       1    i915
drm_kms_helper          126976      1    i915
drm                             356352      5   i915,drm_kms_helper
video                           ls 36864    2   i915,acer_wmi
```

Also there is no entry in `/sys/class/backlight` in Debian, while in Lubuntu I have `intel_backlight`. I read somewhere that when there is no entry in `/sys/class/backlight` it means that the Linux kernel thinks that the display is a very old one where there is a physical brightness switch. But I don't think the kernel that Debian and Ubuntu use are that different.

Please help me get `xbacklight` to work on Debian. Thanks!

Edit: I add the error messages in `dmesg`:
Lubuntu:

```
[    0.182944] ACPI Error: No handler for Region [RAM_] (ffff88017b4b8558) [EmbeddedControl] (20150619/evregion-163)
[    0.182955] ACPI Error: Region EmbeddedControl (ID=3) has no handler (20150619/exfldio-297)
[    0.182966] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB_.PCI0.LPCB.EC0_._REG] (Node ffff88017b4b9208), AE_NOT_EXIST (20150619/psparse-536)
[    0.183081] ACPI Error: No handler for Region [RAM_] (ffff88017b4b8558) [EmbeddedControl] (20150619/evregion-163)
[    0.183089] ACPI Error: Region EmbeddedControl (ID=3) has no handler (20150619/exfldio-297)
[    0.183097] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB_.PCI0.LPCB.EC0_._REG] (Node ffff88017b4b9208), AE_NOT_EXIST (20150619/psparse-536)
[    0.243103] acpi PNP0A08:00: _OSC failed (AE_ERROR); disabling ASPM
[    1.971340] [drm:valleyview_update_wm [i915]] *ERROR* timed out waiting for Punit DDR DVFS request
[    2.356840] [drm:valleyview_update_wm [i915]] *ERROR* timed out waiting for Punit DDR DVFS request
[    3.270826] [drm:valleyview_update_wm [i915]] *ERROR* timed out waiting for Punit DDR DVFS request
[   16.051457] EXT4-fs (sda5): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
[  110.693938] [drm:valleyview_update_wm [i915]] *ERROR* timed out waiting for Punit DDR DVFS request
[  116.909911] [drm:valleyview_update_wm [i915]] *ERROR* timed out waiting for Punit DDR DVFS request
[  118.610041] [drm:valleyview_update_wm [i915]] *ERROR* timed out waiting for Punit DDR DVFS request
[  221.721939] [drm:valleyview_update_wm [i915]] *ERROR* timed out waiting for Punit DDR DVFS request
[  223.091774] [drm:valleyview_update_wm [i915]] *ERROR* timed out waiting for Punit DDR DVFS request
```

Debian:

```
[    0.200280] ACPI Error: No handler for Region [RAM_] (ffff88017f056938) [EmbeddedControl] (20140424/evregion-163)
[    0.200290] ACPI Error: Region EmbeddedControl (ID=3) has no handler (20140424/exfldio-297)
[    0.200300] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB_.PCI0.LPCB.EC0_._REG] (Node ffff88017f057f18), AE_NOT_EXIST (20140424/psparse-536)
[    0.200412] ACPI Error: No handler for Region [RAM_] (ffff88017f056938) [EmbeddedControl] (20140424/evregion-163)
[    0.200419] ACPI Error: Region EmbeddedControl (ID=3) has no handler (20140424/exfldio-297)
[    0.200426] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB_.PCI0.LPCB.EC0_._REG] (Node ffff88017f057f18), AE_NOT_EXIST (20140424/psparse-536)
[    0.389651] acpi PNP0A08:00: _OSC failed (AE_ERROR); disabling ASPM
[    8.578880] EXT4-fs (dm-0): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
[    9.899828] usb 1-5.1: Direct firmware load failed with error -2
[    9.902636] ath3k: probe of 1-5.1:1.0 failed with error -12
```

According to [this site](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Debugging/Backlight), not having any entries in `/sys/class/backlight` might also mean problems with the ACPI backlight driver. There were some error messages regarding ACPI in `dmesg`, but unfortunately not only in Debian, but also in Ubuntu. In Ubuntu backlight control works, though.

Edit2: The kernel version of Debian 8.3.0 is 3.16.0-4-amd64, while the kernel of Lubuntu 15.10 is of a newer version 4.2.0-27-generic. I wonder if that makes a difference...

Comment: Check with dmesg -H for errors (e.g. missing firmware).  Note that debian doesn't install by default non-free firmware.

Comment: Check that you have `firmware-misc-nonfree` installed. `dpkg -l firmware-misc-nonfree`. The kernel version is not that likely to make a difference, but you can certainly try the `4.3` kernel jessie backport if you want, in parallel with the default 3.16 kernel.

Comment: @FaheemMitha: `firmware-misc-nonfree` was already installed, because I deliberately installed from the non-free firmware version.

Answer (score 1):

I installed the precompiled `4.3.0-0.bpo.1-amd64` kernel following [this guide](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/debian-26/kernel-version-4-1-and-4-2-upgrade-compile-guide-4175552272/), and immediately an entry `intel_backlight` appeared in `/sys/class/backlight`, and the program `xbacklight` worked, too.

(It seems like the hardware was so new that it was not supported by the old kernel. I just got this notebook.)

Now, I am kind of excited that this works, since it was the main reason why I could not work with Debian, despite everything that I dislike about Ubuntu, and everything I like about Debian. But the kernel upgrade already shows some side effects. iceweasel crashes a lot now. And that is one of the few programs I tested until now.

So, even though it is not a perfect solution, it is good enough for me.

Comment: 4.4. is also available, in Debian experimental. This may also be worth trying. It helped another poster recently. Link available on request. You could also try an updated iceweasel.

Comment: @FaheemMitha: How do I update iceweasel? It is already the newest version...

Comment: `38.6.1esr-1~deb8u1` is the latest iceweasel version on jessie. You could backport a version from unstable or experimental. But first try https://wiki.debian.org/Iceweasel#Iceweasel_is_consistently_crashing_on_a_website. Also, try 4.4. That may work better.